# How Can i Fatch data from 2d array in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

My Data In This Form

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [scan] => MRI any one spine segment with screening whole spine             
        [charges] => 100
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [scan] => MRI leg/thigh/hard palate/one body part
        [charges] => 100
     )

)
```

Comment: Do you have a question ?

Comment: If you are returning array from php to Ajax call. Then instead return JSON from php and read as object in javascript (in case this is what you asked). And at least write the question here...

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna access the second dimension of your array, you can just do this:

```
myArray[0]['scan']
```